# Finding angle between the x-axis and a vector on the unit circle

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, math, vector

I have a function that that finds the angle between the unit circle vector `[1,0]` and a vector on the unit circle.

```py
import numpy as np

def angle(a):
    b = [0,1]
    if a[1] >= 0:
        return round(np.degrees(np.arccos(np.dot(a, b)/ (np.linalg.norm(a) * np.linalg.norm(b)))), 2)
    else:
        return 180 + round(np.degrees(np.arccos(np.dot(a, b)/ (np.linalg.norm(a) * np.linalg.norm(b)))), 2)

print(angle(np.array([1,0])))
90.0

print(angle(np.array([-4,2])))
63.43 # This value should be 150

print(angle(np.array([-1,0])))
90.0 # This value should be 180

print(angle(np.array([0,-1])))
360.0 # This value should be 270
```

- How do I establish that the input `a` is always a 2D vector?
- How do I change the code so that vectors below the x-axis (i.e. negative y-values) show the correct value?

Comment: how do you want vectors below the x-axis to be represented?  -5 or 355?

Comment: There's an `arctan2` function that does what you want to do with `angle` function.

Comment: @anon01 represented like 355 would be ideal

Comment: assert(type(a) == np.ndarray) & assert(a.size == 2) could help with input validation. Throws an error if those conditions are not true.

Comment: @QuangHoang how would I implement this function into the code?

Comment: [https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ndim.html#numpy.ndarray.ndim](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ndim.html#numpy.ndarray.ndim)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the x vector wrong. It should be

`b = [1,0]`

given that the first coordinate is the x axis and the second one is the y axis. If you put this correct b vector, all the computations work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

One way to define a function that expects inputs is to leave both as separate args (this also fixes some bugs and simplifies the logic to get your angle values):

```
def angle(x, y):
    
    rad = np.arctan2(y, x)
    degrees = np.int(rad*180/np.pi)
    if degrees < 0:
        degrees = 360 + degrees
    return degrees
```

Incidentally, `atan2` has input order `y, x` which is easy to mix up.  An advantage to specifying them separately is you can help avoid that.  If you want to keep the input as an array, something like this helps you validate the length:

```
def angle(a):
    
    if len(a) != 2:
        raise IndexError("vector a expected to be length 2")        
    x = a[0]
    y = a[1]
    rad = np.arctan2(y, x)
    degrees = np.int(rad*180/np.pi)
    if degrees < 0:
        degrees = 360 + degrees
    return degrees
```

Comment: I think it should be `360 + degress` because degrees is negative

Answer (score 0):

<strike>To establish a is always a 2D vector, you can check it's length : `if len(a) == 2`. you can additionally check if it's a list or a tuple with : `if type(a) in [list, tuple] and len(a) == 2:`</strike>

EDIT : my bad just noticed it's actually numpy arrays, in that case : `if isinstance(x, np.ndarray) and x.shape[0] == 2`

EDIT 2 : from the comments : `x.ndim == 2` sounds better.

Comment: [https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ndim.html#numpy.ndarray.ndim](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ndim.html#numpy.ndarray.ndim)